# Listener on Map idle event is not working on Google maps api v3.28.18

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I needed to downgrade my google maps version to 3.27.13 because the version 3.28.18 is not triggering the idle event on the corresponding code below.

whenever the map is moved, it invokes the changeViewport to load geoms

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', changeViewport)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had the same problem using the latest google api. Using Google's example on: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&v=3.27&callback=initMap"></script>
```

I'd recommend changing the query parameter to v=3.27. The solution I was working with had v=3 to which I'm presuming uses the latest Google API updates. Changing it to 3.27 resolved my issue.

Comment: That's actually what I did. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Appears Google has deprecated v3.27 since last conversation May, 2017. A warning now comes up on console with

"Google Maps API warning: RetiredVersion https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#retired-version"

Going to that page presents the following info.
RetiredVersion  Warning 
You may have supplied a retired version in your script element. The versions 3.0 - 3.27 have been retired, and you might be receiving 3.28 instead. Please update your application to use one of the available versions.

In our application we had continually added and removed event listeners to the idle function. We refactored so that the idle event was only registered once during the initialization and that solved our problem.